# Alias for an inner select in both union statement parts

Tags: mariadb

Is there way to give an alias for the inner select statement (SELECT defined data) that is used in both parts of union statement:

```
SELECT T1.CLASS_RATE,T1.BEDS, (T1.CC - T2.CC) RC
    FROM (SELECT defined data)
        WHERE T2.CC IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT T1.CLASS_RATE,T1.BEDS, T1.CC RC
    FROM (SELECT defined data)
        WHERE T2.CC IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  No.  (At least not until CTEs in 8.0 or 10.2.)

Long answer:  You are working too hard:

```
SELECT T1.CLASS_RATE, T1.BEDS,
       (T1.CC - IFNULL(T2.CC, 0)) RC
    FROM defined data
```